# How to include matplotlib into a C++ project

Tags: python, c++, git, matplotlib

I have a project that is coded entirely in `C++`, in which users code in Python (front-end) to use the package. And since the back-end is using `C++`, in order to show graphs other developers have used `VTK`.

Now since the front-end language is Python, implementing plotting to `ipython notebook`, using `matplotlib` is definitely a good call. Now, after hours of research, I have come across this [git](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) that looks like it would do the job. My question is: Is this the right thing to do - calling `python` wrapper for `C++`, like [this](http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html#boost-python) tutorial is suggesting? Cause even the git does not seem to fully include all `matplotlib` utilities. Or is there any better options?